# Recyclerview Not showing firstTime item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have Recycler view in app I use recycler view in navigation drawer means fragment
when reyclerview is empty and when I add item in recycler view that not show but after I refresh fragment and after I add item then is showing immediately but not show first time why. I am stuck.

here is my code-:

```
     @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_consultant_note_fragment, container, false);
        mSp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        consulatantnoterecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.consulatantnote_display_recycler);
        swipeRefreshLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        nodatafound = v.findViewById(R.id.nodatafound);
        // GetConsulatantNote();
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        consulatantnoterecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        consulatantnoterecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

       return v;
    }

     void GetConsulatantNote() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.show();
        if (!Utils.isInternetAvailable(getActivity(), true))
            return;

        final ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        ConsultantNote request = new ConsultantNote();
        request.setActionBy(Integer.valueOf(mSp.getString(Constant.ActionBy, "")));
        request.setInPatientID(Integer.valueOf(mSp.getString(Constant.InPatientID, "")));
        request.setToken(mSp.getString(Constant.TOKEN, ""));
        request.setCreatedBy(Integer.valueOf(mSp.getString(Constant.MasterUserID, "")));
        request.setIsActive(1);


        ServiceRequest serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest();
        serviceRequest.setOppID(**);
        serviceRequest.setParameters(request);

        Call<ConsultantNoteResponse> consultantNoteResponseCall = apiInterface.SaveConsulatantNote(serviceRequest);
        consultantNoteResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<ConsultantNoteResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ConsultantNoteResponse> call, Response<ConsultantNoteResponse> response) {

                if (response.body().getSuccess() == true && response.body().getValidated() == false) {
                    if (!response.body().getValidationErrors().isEmpty()) {
                        Nodatafound = true;
                        List<ValidationError> validationErrors = response.body().getValidationErrors();
                        for (int i = 0; i < validationErrors.size(); i++) {
                            ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
                            error.setErrorMessage(validationErrors.get(i).getErrorMessage());
                            Log.d("error", "" + validationErrors.get(i).getErrorMessage());
                        }
                        // Toast.makeText(DoctorCollection.this, "Records not found for opd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                if (response.body().getSuccess() == true && response.body().getValidated() == true) {
                    //data
                    consultantNotes = new ArrayList<>();
                    consultantNotes.clear();
                    List<ConsultantNote> notes = response.body().getConsultantNotes();
                    consulatantnoterecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    nodatafound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {

                        ConsultantNote note = new ConsultantNote();

                        note.setCreatedByUserFullName(notes.get(i).getCreatedByUserFullName());
                        note.setConsultantNotesDateTime(notes.get(i).getConsultantNotesDateTime());
                        note.setPatientProgress(notes.get(i).getPatientProgress());
                        note.setCreatedBy(notes.get(i).getCreatedBy());
                        note.setInPatientConsultantNoteID(notes.get(i).getInPatientConsultantNoteID());
                        note.setProblemsAndInterventions(notes.get(i).getProblemsAndInterventions());

                        consultantNotes.add(note);
                    }


                    //consulatantnoterecyclerView.setAdapter(consultantNoteAdpater);

                    setAdapterData(consultantNotes);
                    onItemDelete();
                    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                if (Nodatafound) {
                    consulatantnoterecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    nodatafound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ConsultantNoteResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        dialog.dismiss();
    }


  void onItemDelete() {

    final ConsultantNoteAdpater noteAdpater = new ConsultantNoteAdpater(context, consultantNotes);
    consulatantnoterecyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdpater);

    noteAdpater.setOnItemDeleteClickListener(new ConsultantNoteAdpater.OnItemClickDeleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final int position, final Integer NoteId) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder innermsg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            innermsg.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this consultant note ?");
            innermsg.setCancelable(false);
            innermsg.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    consultantNotes.remove(position);
                    noteAdpater.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    noteAdpater.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, consultantNotes.size());
                    DeleteConsulatantNote(NoteId);
                    noteAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    GetConsulatantNote();
                }
            });
            innermsg.setNegativeButton("cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            innermsg.show();
        }


    });

}

private void setAdapterData(List<ConsultantNote> data) {
    if (data != null) {
        ArrayList<ConsultantNote> notes = new ArrayList<>();
        notes.clear();
        notes.addAll(consultantNotes);

        adapter = new ConsultantNoteAdpater(getActivity(), notes);
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, consultantNotes.size());
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        consulatantnoterecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

Here is my adapter code of recyclerview-:

```
public class ConsultantNoteAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConsultantNoteAdpater.holder> {


LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;
List<ConsultantNote> consultantNotes;
private SharedPreferences mSp;
public OnItemClickDeleteListener onItemClickDeleteListener;

public ConsultantNoteAdpater(Context c, List<ConsultantNote> notes) {
    context = c;
    consultantNotes = notes;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_consultant_note_adpater, parent, false);
    mSp = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new holder(v);
}

public interface OnItemClickDeleteListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, Integer NoteId);
}

public void setOnItemDeleteClickListener(OnItemClickDeleteListener onItemClickDeleteListener) {
    this.onItemClickDeleteListener = onItemClickDeleteListener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder holder, final int position) {

    final ConsultantNote note = consultantNotes.get(position);


    holder.createdby.setText(Html.fromHtml(createdby + "" + note.getCreatedByUserFullName()));


    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onItemClickDeleteListener != null) {
                //get pateint consulatant note id
                onItemClickDeleteListener.onItemClick(position, note.getInPatientConsultantNoteID());
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return consultantNotes.size();
}



class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView date, createdby;
    ImageView delete;

    public holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.consulatant_datetime);
        createdby = itemView.findViewById(R.id.consulatant_createdby);
        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteconsultant);
    }
  }
}
```

I am using retrofit to get data from api so if any one can help!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: where are you calling `GetConsulatantNote`

Comment: onresume I did put on resume

Comment: @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (new InternetDialog(getActivity()).connectiondetect()) {
            GetConsulatantNote();
        }
    }

Comment: why are you setting adapter twice ? Once using your setAdapter method and then again in delete method ? Also try removing the notify Item Changed line

Comment: still nothing I set both in one  adapter and still nothing

Comment: You are not able to see the data in the first time because it's not loaded yet from Retrofit. By the time you call the fragment second time, it get loaded and hence you can see the data.

Comment: no I debug and array size is one not empty still nothing @Umang

Comment: @JigarFumakiya Did you try calling without Retrofit Component? I mean just manually add 5 items in the list and try if its working as expected.

Comment: still nothing bro.....

Comment: Still same thing? @JigarFumakiya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183001/discussion-between-jigar-fumakiya-and-umang-ssurman).